# Group by date in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, group-by, mapreduce, mongoose

I'm running a blog-style web application on AppFog (ex Nodester).
It's written in NodeJS + Express and uses Mongoose framework to persist to MongoDB.

MongoDB is version 1.8 and I don't know whether AppFog is going to upgrade it to 2.2 or not.

Why this intro? Well, now my "posts" are shown in a basic "paginated" visualization, I mean they're just picked up from mongo, sorted by date descending, a page at a time. Here's a snippet:

```
Post
                .find({pubblicato:true})
                .populate("commenti")
                .sort("-dataInserimento")
                .skip(offset)
                .limit(archivePageSize)
                .exec(function(err,docs) {
                    var result = {};
                    result.postsArray = (!err) ? docs : [];
                    result.currentPage = currentPage;
                    result.pages = howManyPages;
                    cb(null, result);
            });
```

Now, my goal is to GROUP BY 'dataInserimento' and show posts like a "diary", I mean:

1st page => 2012/10/08: I show 3 posts

2nd page => 2012/10/10: I show 2 posts (2012/10/09 has no posts, so I don't allow a white page)

3rd page => 2012/10/11: 35 posts and so on...

My idea is to get first the list of all dates with grouping (and maybe counting posts for each day) then build the pages link and, when a page (date) is visited, query like above, adding date as parameter.

*SOLUTIONS*:

- Aggregation framework would be perfect for that, but I can't get my hands on that version of Mongo, now
- Using .group() in some way, but the idea it doesn't work in sharded environments does NOT excite me! :-(
- writing a MAP-REDUCE! I think this is the right way to go but I can't imagine how map() and reduce() should be written.

Can you help me with a little example, please?

Thanks

***EDIT*** :

The answer of peshkira is correct, however, I don't know if I need exactly that.

I mean, I will have URLs like /archive/2012/10/01, /archive/2012/09/20, and so on.

In each page, it's enough to have the date for querying for posts. But then I have to show "NEXT" or "PREV" links, so I need to know what's the next or previous day containing posts, if any. Maybe can I just query for posts with dates bigger or smaller than the current, and get the first one's date?

Comment: Map reduce would be the way to go.
You may want to have a look at this (though I guess you might have already seen it)
http://wmilesn.com/2011/07/code/how-to-map-reduce-with-mongoose-mongodb-express-node-js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have something similar as:

```
{
"author" : "john doe",
"title" : "Post 1",
"article" : "test",
"created" : ISODate("2012-02-17T00:00:00Z")
}
{
"author" : "john doe",
"title" : "Post 2",
"article" : "foo",
"created" : ISODate("2012-02-17T00:00:00Z")
}
{
"author" : "john doe",
"title" : "Post 3",
"article" : "bar",
"created" : ISODate("2012-02-18T00:00:00Z")
}
{
"author" : "john doe",
"title" : "Post 4",
"article" : "foo bar",
"created" : ISODate("2012-02-20T00:00:00Z")
}
{
"author" : "john doe",
"title" : "Post 5",
"article" : "lol cat",
"created" : ISODate("2012-02-20T00:00:00Z")
}
```

then you can use map reduce as follows:

**Map**

It just emits the date as key and the post title. You can change the title to the _id, which will probably be more useful to you. If you store the time of the date you will want to use only the date (without time) as the key, otherwise mongo will group by date time and not only date. In my test case all posts have the same time 00:00:00 so it does not matter.

```
function map() {
  emit(this.created, this.title);
}
```

**Reduce**

It does nothing more, then just push all values for a key to an array and then the array is wrapped in a result object, because mongo does not allow arrays to be the result of a reduce function.

```
function reduce(key, values) {
  var array = [];
  var res = {posts:array};
  values.forEach(function (v) {res.posts.push(v);});
  return res;
}
```

**Execute**

Using `db.runCommand({mapreduce: "posts", map: map, reduce: reduce, out: {inline: 1}})` will output the following result:

```
{
"results" : [
    {
        "_id" : ISODate("2012-02-17T00:00:00Z"),
        "value" : {
            "posts" : [
                "Post 2",
                "Post 1"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : ISODate("2012-02-18T00:00:00Z"),
        "value" : "Post 3"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ISODate("2012-02-20T00:00:00Z"),
        "value" : {
            "posts" : [
                "Post 5",
                "Post 4"
            ]
        }
    }
],
...
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH! I'll try and let you know!

Comment: you can execute the map reduce job in order to find out all distinct dates and build your history/archive that is paginated in the frontend. (Note, that you don't have to do the map reduce each time) Then based on on the url you can extract the date parameter and just create a query that returns all posts from that date. `db.posts.find({'created': new ISODate("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss")})` . Is this what you mean?

Note that for the distinct you can also use db.posts.distinct('created'), but it is limited in Mongo and will not sort. So I would stick to MapReduce if you plan to have lots of posts

Comment: "Note, that you don't have to do the map reduce each time" so..... may I have a separate collection with those MR results?

Comment: yes! take a look here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-IncrementalMapreduce You can either output the collection, store and replace it each time you execute or you can also just merge the new results with the old ones. It is pretty neat!

Comment: Ok I'll use incremental map reduce, but help me finalize this example, please. I'll have the collection like {"date":"2012-10-01","count":"11"},{"date":"2012-10-03","count":"25"}. When I am in the first page, how can I know the next page is "2012-10-03"? I mean querying the MR result collection with the current date (page) as a parameter and get back the "next" day-date-page.

Comment: why don't you query the map reduce collection for all its (_ids) in that case the dates. then you can just get the next one. Is this ok?

Comment: I think that just querying for documents with dates smaller / greater than the current and using limit(1) would get my job done (knowing what's the next valid date).... however, it's good if it doesn't impact on performance. I meant I was in trouble getting the "next" element of an array.... :)